# Close SharePoint pop-up window from python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, ironpython

I have a python script which works with a SharePoint library. It takes Excels documents which are in the library, reads in the read-only mode the information and closes the documents. 
The problem happens when the document is checked out by me: before closing the workbook Excel asks me: 'This document is still checked out to you. Would you like to discard check out to allow others to edit the document?'
How can I close this dialogue in python? It freezes my script and it cannot proceed handling other files.

Here is some code I use:

```
def uploadToMySQL(conn, #some parameters):
    ex = Excel.ApplicationClass()
    ex.Visible = False
    ex.DisplayAlerts = False
    for sp_car in upl_sp_cars:
        try:
            uploadExcelCARDetails(conn, ex, sp_car)

        except Exception as e:

        finally:
            if ex:
                ex.Quit()

def uploadExcelCARDetails(conn, ex, car):
    wb = None
    try:

    except Exception as e:

    finally:
        if wb:
            print "Closing workbook...."
            wb.Close(False)
```

The problem occurs in the last line of the code, a pop-up window arises there.

Thanks,
Egor